# windows cURL cmd and multiline

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have installed cURL command line for windows.

Now I want to use this cURL for a REST api (redmine).

The most basic script I want to create is to push a new "past".
But the problem is, one past can contains multiline text.

To put a new past I use:

```
curl -k -s -H "X-Redmine-API-Key: %API_KEY%" --data-urlencode "paste[text]=%TEXT%" %URL%
```

But the problem is when %TEXT% is composed by more than one line, the windows cmd failed.

Ex:

```
curl -k -s -H "X-Redmine-API-Key: XXXXXX" --data-urlencode "paste[text]=ST_METHOD_POST',    'POST',    true);
define('HTTP_REQUEST_METHOD_PUT',     'PUT',     true);
define('HTTP_REQUEST_METHOD_DELETE',  'DELETE',  true);" "https://etc"
```

And cmd stops after the first newline...

I try parse TEXT before running cmd by adding ^ at the end of the line to simulate multiline win cmd but does not work...

---

**Update 1:**

I try

```
curl -k -s -H "X-Redmine-API-Key: %API_KEY%" --data-urlencode "paste[text]@tmp.txt" %URL%
```

where tmp.txt equals to

```
hello world
```

but the request is transformed to

```
{"paste":{"id":xxx,"author_id":xxx,"project_id":xxx,"title":"Paste #xxx","text":" 
■h\u0000e\u0000l\u0000l\u0000o\u0000 \u0000w\u0000o\u0000r\u0000l\u0000d\u0000",
"created_on":"2012-11-26T09:24:15Z","updated_on":"2012-11-26T09:24:15Z"}}
```

And the final result does not work

Comment: hello can you help me with this  : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26719068/how-can-i-run-this-curl-command-via-command-line-interface

Comment: Your question had been validated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To successfully pass a linefeed to another command, you should use delayed expansion instead of perecent expansion.

Try it with

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set LF=^


set "text=ST_METHOD_POST',    'POST',    true);"
set "text=!text!!LF!define('HTTP_REQUEST_METHOD_PUT',     'PUT',     true);"
set "text=!text!!LF!define('HTTP_REQUEST_METHOD_DELETE',  'DELETE',  true);"
echo ----
echo !text!
echo ----
curl -k -s -H "X-Redmine-API-Key: %API_KEY%" --data-urlencode "paste[text]=!TEXT!" !URL!
```

If `text` really contains linefeeds than this should work.

Comment: For ex. my src is a multiline file. If you write set /p text=<tmp.txt the variable just only send the first line if i use !text! on curl cmd. May i need to loop over with for and concat with char "^" all line into one var ?

Comment: You can use a for loop to read multiple line from a file,but when concanating you need to add !LF! linefeeds. I edited my answer

Comment: hello jeb i really dont understand your answer can you help me with this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26719068/how-can-i-run-this-curl-command-via-command-line-interface

Answer (score 3):

Here's what works perfectly to issue multi-line SSL POST curl request on Windows (it also works from batch/cmd file):

```
curl -i -k -X POST -H "Content-Type: text/xml" -d             ^
"^<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ?^>                ^
    ^<Transaction^>                                           ^
        ^<SomeParam1^>AD6084-01^</SomeParam1^>                ^
        ^<Password^>SomePassW0rd^</Password^>                 ^
        ^<Transaction_Type^>00^</Transaction_Type^>           ^
        ^<CardHoldersName^>John Smith^</CardHoldersName^>     ^
        ^<DollarAmount^>9.97^</DollarAmount^>                 ^
        ^<Card_Number^>4111111111111111^</Card_Number^>       ^
        ^<Expiry_Date^>1118^</Expiry_Date^>                   ^
        ^<VerificationStr2^>123^</VerificationStr2^>          ^
        ^<CVD_Presence_Ind^>1^</CVD_Presence_Ind^>            ^
        ^<Reference_No^>Some Reference Text^</Reference_No^>  ^
        ^<Client_Email^>john@smith.com^</Client_Email^>       ^
        ^<Client_IP^>123.4.56.7^</Client_IP^>                 ^
        ^<Tax1Amount^>^</Tax1Amount^>                         ^
        ^<Tax2Amount^>^</Tax2Amount^>                         ^
    ^</Transaction^>                                          ^
" "https://example.com/transaction"
```

Answer (score 1):

Windows environment variables don't support multiline strings. Perhaps you can write the text (including the leading `paste[text]=`) to a file and use

```
curl --data-urlencode data@FILE ...
```

Comment: I try like you said.
A file with the text (on my ex just hello world without multiline). Then i composed my curl --data-urlencode paste[text]@file.txt ...
The problem it's curl convert my text to "text":"¦h\u0000e\u0000l\u0000l\u0000o\u0000 \u0000w\u0000o\u0000r\u0000l\u0000d\u0000",.
And i read that \u0000 means null char o.O So the final result does not work :'(

Comment: Environment variables can contain multiline text, the simplest is the linefeed itself. Defined by `set LF=^` followed by two empty lines

Comment: @Kakawait That's not `curl` converting your text, but your editor saving the text in unicode format.

Comment: lol ok my bad. Finally I used the method using EnableDelayedExpansion :) But i will try with a no unicode format