# How can I run this curl command via command line interface?

Tags: curl, command-line, cmd

I am trying to upload my artworks to the deviantart via api interface

They give below line as example

```
 curl https://www.deviantart.com/api/v1/oauth2/stash/submit \
-F "title=My great stash item&artist_comments=This is a great image&keywords=test image" \
-F access_token=Alph4num3r1ct0k3nv4lu3 \
-F "test=@path/to/image.png"
```

I changed parameters with my own parameters and installed windows curl

However i have 0 idea how to execute this multi-line command with curl

help is appreciated ty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put all in one line, or, replace the `\` character at the end of the lines with `^`, the continuation character for batch files

Not sure about your parameters, but you should remember that `cmd` has a line length limit: 2048 for XP, 8192 for Vista and later versions of the OS

Another problem could be the characters.

`%` characters inside a batch file needs to be escaped, replacing them with `%%`

`&),=` characters must be in a string enclosed in quotes or escaped as `^&`, ...

Comment: all in 1 line failed gonna try ^ ty